# Django foreign key ordering / position

Tags: django, model

I've got a list of items in a Django Model that I'd like to be able to set the order of. Basically a linked list.

```
class List(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Item(models.Model):
      list     = models.ForeignKey(List)
      position = models.PositiveIntegerField()
      data     = models.AnyField() 

      class Meta:
            unique_together = ('list', 'position')
            ordering = ['position']
```

Here's the model I have in mind. For each ListItem in List, the list position must be unique but it also must be without gaps (e.g. deleting item 4 does not result in the position sequence [1, 2, 3, 5, 6].

Answer (score 2):

While writing the question I stumbled upon a [possible solution](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering).

```
class Item(models.Model):
    list = models.ForeignKey(List)
     # ...

    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = 'list'
```

This model could then be manipulated like so:

```
list = List.objects.get(id=1)
list.get_item_order() == [1, 2, 3]
```

The order of a List object’s related Item objects can be set by passing in a list of Item primary keys:

```
list.set_item_order([3, 1, 2])
```

---

Haven't tried this code so feel free to correct me (comments or edits).

Comment: why not use the pk instead of the position field? pk is already give you unique id

Comment: Because pk is incremented for each addition - regardless of the List fk and maybe that pk should be placed in the middle of a list.

Comment: 'PhotoQueue' object has no attribute 'get_photos_order'
what about this error?